# Changing the contents of a DIV  based on drop-down selection

Tags: javascript, onchange, innerhtml

On a web page, the contents of a div must dynamically change when a particular selection is made from a drop down list. Below is my code, I don't know where I am going wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fn()
{
    var x = document.getElementsById("select").selectedIndex;
    var y = document.getElementById("a").innerHTML;

    if (X == "0")
    {
        y = " So.. ur a conman" ;
    }
    else
    {
        y = "oops";
    }
}
window.onload = fn() ;
x.onchange = fn() ;
</script>

<body>
<select name="select" id="select">
<option value="consulting"> Consulting </option>
<option value="industry"> Industry </option>
</select>
<div id="a" style="background-color:blue; width:1200px; height:20px; color:black;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The right command is getElementById (not elements, like in your var x, since id is unique)

Answer (score 2):

- Javascript is case sensitive, so `x` is not the same as `X`. Change `X` to `x`.
- `y` receives the *value* of the inner html, not a *reference* to the inner html. This means you can't change innerHTML through `y`.
- When assigning to window.onload, you are currently assigning the return value of the function. You want to assign the function itself, so it should be `window.onload = fn;`.

Improved but not tested code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var x = document.getElementsById("select");
var y = document.getElementById("a");

function fn()
{

    if (x.selectedIndex == 0)
    {
        y.innerHTML = " So.. ur a conman" ;
    }
    else
    {
        y.innerHTML = "oops";
    }
}

window.onload = fn ;
x.onchange = fn ;

</script>
```

Also, note that your browser has developer tools which will tell you about some mistakes. Depending on which browser you are using for testing, you might be able to press `F12` to open those tools. Have a look at the console there, and you'll see messages similar to `'X' is not defined`.

Comment: Thank you Supr... The DIV loads after the window but DIV contents do not change after the drop down selection is changed to Industry...

Comment: That's because `x` only exists inside the function. I've updated the code now so that it exists outside the function as well. Make sure the code is at the end of the document though, or else it won't be able to find the elements.

Comment: thanks for ur tips useful for a newbie like me who didnt take JS Classes seriously. works like a charm.. I had changed variable scope to global by taking them out of the function but totally forgot that elements must be created before being referenced in a script